# Invalid `Podfile` file: unterminated string meets end of file

Tags: xcode6, cocoapods, xcode7, command-line-tool

I am trying to install pod file but getting following error :

```
Faizs-MacBook-Pro:newj faizfareed$  pod install

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: unterminated string meets end of file.

 #  from /Users/faizfareed/Desktop/NewJson/NewJ/Podfile:4
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Here goes detailed picture of command line tool -

[image: error]

could anyone help me resolving this issue?

Comment: Can you show us the full podfile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your pod line is missing a **'**

Should be: pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'